# What is the right way to map different domains in Google Search Console?

Tags: google-search-console, domains, cctld

I have 2 domains that I want to "map" together in Google Search Console. Each domain is for a different countries:  `example.ch` for Switzerland and `example.de` for Germany. How can I group them in the right way so they can share their rankings?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more. e.g: Are you saying you want to merge 2 domains into 1, or you want both domains live independently, ranking in their respective country google results or something else.  Try and edit your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

In the classic view of Webmaster Tools, this can be achieved by Grouping Properties into 'Sets'.

This is directly available on `https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/set-edit`.

Up to 200 properties can be added in a set, including https vs https, www and non-www version of web properties.

in the new search console, there will be a new way to handle this but is currently unavailable.

**Source**: [Official Documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6338828?hl=en)

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, it sounds more like he wants to merge the domain into a single domain, hence 'so they can share their ranking'